# What's the right licensing to sell a web app, without renounce to reuse the code?

Tags: licensing

I'm making a web app for a client who is probably going to use it for commercial use. I'm not affialited with me, nor we are commercial partners.

However, although I'm making this project for this client, I want to be sure I can reuse the same code on future projects.

I know there are many licenses (GPL etc.) but it's not clear to me which one complies the following requirments:

- The code can be sold by me to the client (so he pays me for the code)
- The client may use the code for commercial use
- I still own the ownership on the code, i.e. , I can reuse the code for future works, either in open source works or other projects (which I may sell)

Furthermore, it's not clear to me: When I choose I license how can I "apply" it? I mean: who "certifies" my app is licensed udner that specific licence and do I have to pay for this "certification"?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing and contacting

Comment: @DougM et al: According to the about page, software licensing is **on topic** for programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you do this is by *entering into a contract* with the client.  If you wish, you can do that by selling him a license.  In it, you specify the following conditions:

- The code can be sold by me to the client (so he pays me for the code)
- The client may use the code for commercial use
- I still own the ownership on the code, i.e. , I can reuse the code for future works, either in open source works or other projects (which I may sell)

Comment: Is there not any similar license like "I give u the code (for free) but I can reuse it"? And any clue on how to "enter into the contract"? I mean.. from the legal point of view..

Comment: You'd have to talk to a lawyer about that.  The tricky part about agreements like this is defining terms like *"commercial use," "ownership" and "sale,"*  in ways that make your intent unambiguous and clear.

Comment: what about the license? There not exist a license that anyhow allow me to reuse my code (without making my customer being forced to comply with this)?

Comment: You're trying to get me to say that there's a cheap, easy way for you to do this without you having to think carefully about it or consult a professional for legal advice.  There isn't.

Comment: I just asked an advice since I don't know anything about legal :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Copyright licenses only restrict what *others* can do with *your code*.

With that in mind, as long as the code remains yours, your first and third bullet points become irrelevant, because they are about what you do with your own code.

In principle, any code that you write is owned by you (as in, you control who can do what with it), but there are a few exceptions to that principle, where the most obvious one is because you wrote the code as part of your job. A more tricky situation is that in some cases where you do freelance work and you haven't stipulated otherwise in your contracts, then the code could be owned by your client. If you want to retain ownership of your code, you should make clear provisions about that in contracts that you sign that involve (the writing of) the code.

---

Once the ownership issue is resolved in your contracts, the biggest question that remains for choosing a license is what you want to allow *your client* to do with the code.
b
Most copyright licenses don't restrict how you use the code (so commercial use is not a problem), but they restrict how the code can be modified or redistributed.
If you don't want to allow modification or redistribution, the standard "all rights reserved" copyright 'license' is sufficient (How you use the software is not generally considered one of those reserved rights).

---

Application of a copyright license is done simply by stating in the source code that copyright license X applies and by adding the additional license texts and notifications to your project as required by that license.

There is no authority that certifies that a particular license applies and it is your job to look out for violations of the copyright license you use for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the very exhaustive asnwer.
What do you mean by "loose ownership of code you write"?
What I would like to understand is as well what it happens in the scenario "I write the code, I sell the program but there is no contract"? I mean: is there any way that some day the buyer claims the ownership of the code and I can get into some trouble to have written more programs with the same code (as if I copied it, while it's actually the opposite)?

Comment: @dragonmnl: Regarding the ownership, see my edit. Regarding contracts, even a verbal agreement to deliver goods or services and get paid for it is in most jurisdictions seen as a contract. The biggest question then is, did you sell existing code or did you write the code specifically for them, but then it becomes enough of a legal question to consult a lawyer. And if both you and your client try to claim ownership (copyright) of the code, then you really need a lawyer.